# mysqli_result -- Need a string value from result

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, primary-key

I have a query that returns the primary key of a table (this table is stored in an array of tables from a database) written in PHP:

- $link: connection to a database
- $tables: array of database tables
- $x: loop variable

`$primaryKey = mysqli_query($link, "SHOW INDEX FROM ".$tables[$x]);`

`mysqli_query` returns a `mysqli_result`, so what would be the best approach to get the string value of the primary key that I need from the variable that is returned?

Comment: See example #7: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!$primaryKey = $link->query("SHOW INDEX FROM ".$tables[$x])) {
    die("Error! [" . $link->error . "]");
}

$result = $primaryKey->fetch_assoc();
```

`$result` should contain the index